# Mac Mini for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

I would like to know if Mac Mini (mid 2011) with i5, 5gb ram and 500 gb hdd is enough to develop xamarin.ios apps? The one I am looking at have High Sierra on it. Have on mind that I am total noob for Apple products.

I don't mind upgrading it later.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a Mac Mini (mid 2011) as a build server for our Xamarin apps. It works fine for a that purpose. I think it will work for you now. We upgraded ours to 16gb ram and 1TB HD when we got it. After using it a bit, you will probably want to put in more ram and a SSD to speed it up - especially if you are going to use it daily as your primary dev machine.

Comment: My primary dev machine is Surface Pro 3 which is working like a charm. When I want to build/test ios apps I just need to connect to some mac mini and see the process of my work. I am not currently in a position to place a lot of money on equipment so I am looking for a "cheap" solutions that can gandle what I want. If those mac mini are slow with emulators I can always get used iPhone to deploy on it and test on it. In any case building project on mac mini is must have. I don't have enough room for it. What is the minimum mac mini for building and deploying to iPhone?

Comment: I think that this should be fine in your case.